# How to put a JsonElement back into a JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, parsing, replace, key-value

The goal is replace a value in a nested JSON.

Original JSON :

```
{
  "data": {
    "car": {
      "xia": [
        "a0.c904.b0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Expected JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
    "car": {
      "xia": [
        "a0.c234.b0"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My code below gives me the JSONElement but I don't know how to put it back to the json object?

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

    String inputJson = "{\n"
            + "  \"data\": {\n"
            + "    \"car\": {\n"
            + "      \"xia\": [\n"
            + "        \"a0.c904.b0\"\n"
            + "      ]\n"
            + "    }\n"
            + "  }\n"
            + "}";
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(inputJson).getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("car").getAsJsonObject().get("xia");
    String str = jsonElement.getAsString();
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] strs = str.split("\\.");
    String replaced = strs[0] + "." + strs[1].replaceAll("\\d+", "234") + "." + strs[2];
    System.out.println(replaced);
    JsonElement jsonElementReplaced = new JsonParser().parse(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do :

```
    jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("car").getAsJsonObject().add("xia", jsonElementReplaced);
```